# Conjugate Mobius Transformations Are Invariant

Tags: complex-analysis

This is for homework and I was hoping to get some help with clarifying some of the concepts.

The problem is as follows:
Let $f,g$ be conjugate Mobius transformations, say $g=h^{-1} \circ f \circ h$ for a Mobius transformation $h$. Verify $K$ is a $g-invariant$ circle in $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ iff $h(K)$ is invariant under $f$.

My questions are:

1. What does it mean for $f,g$ to be conjugate.
2. What does it mean for K to be a $g-invariant$ circle.

If I can understand these concepts I feel that I can do the rest. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've attempted to talk to my professor and the hint that he gave was that I should apply $h^{-1}\circ f \circ h (K)$.

Answer (score 1):

question 1.  If $g=h^{-1}\circ f\circ h$ (or equivalently $f=h\circ g\circ h^{-1}$) for a Mobius transformation $h$, then $f$ and $g$ are conjugate.

question 2. A circle $K$ is $g$-invariant iff the image $g(K)$ is the same circle $K$.

Comment: Thank you very much. The textbook we are using is not very clear on this. Now this makes far more sense.

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose K is a g-invariant circle. Then $g(K)=K$. However we also know that $g=h^{-1}\circ f\circ h$. Therefore
$$K = g(K) = h^{-1}\circ f\circ h(K)$$
$$h(K) = f\circ h(K)$$
Therefore $h(K)$ is invariant under $f$.

$\Leftarrow$ Suppose $h(K)$ is invariant under $f$. Then

$$h(K) = f\circ h(K)$$

$$K = h^{-1}\circ f\circ h(K)$$
Since $g = h^{-1}\circ f\circ h$ then $K = g(K)$. Therefore $K$ is g-invariant.

Comment: very good. it's perfect.